# Как привязать переменную с TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm

Я начинающий в WPF. Необходимо, чтобы изменения TextBox динамически отображались в локальной переменной. 
Есть переменная в главном окне:

```
private int year;
```

И есть TextBox:

```
<TextBox Name="tb" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="2015" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Как отобразить **значение tb в TextBox** я понял. А вот как теперь отображать **значение TextBox в tb**?

Второй вопрос - где лучше всего делать привязки: в XAML или в коде. Т.е. какой из методом больше соответствует паттерну MVVM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Привязки нужно делать в XAML.
Изначально необходимо привязать ViewModel к DataContext твоего окна.
Пример:

```
using System.Windows;
using WpfApplication.View;
using WpfApplication.ViewModel;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            var mw = new MainWindowView
            {
                DataContext = new MainViewModel()
            };

            mw.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindowView - это твоё окно. MainViewModel - класс, реализующий связь окна с моделью.
В MainViewModel создаешь экземпляр своей модели `MyModel model = new MyModel()`, а в классе MyModel у тебя твоя переменная `year`, необходимо, чтобы она была доступна, например, через свойство `public int Year {get { return year;}...}`.
Затем в коде XAML необходимо сделать привязку через `Binding`:

```
<TextBox Name="tb" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Model.Year}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Вот очень хорошая статья про MVVM для начинающих: http://svyatoslavpankratov.blogspot.ru/2011/11/mvvm-pattern-1.html